# apache index.html no-cache and included resources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a js+html single page app (angular) deployed on apache.

It contains an index.html that includes (using script and link tag) a js and a css file both suffixed with a timestamp to allow refreshing on redeploy.

But now it appears that index.html is getting cached and clients need a 'hard refresh' because the index.html will point to the old timestamps (and the old js and css is loaded locally since on the server there are just the files suffixed with the new time stamp).

If I exclude index.html from cache using :

```
<filesMatch "index\.html$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
```

will this exclude from cache the included js and css? Or the js and css will be cached until I change the time stamp suffix (on next version deploy) as I expect?

Is this the right way to deal with caching of single page apps (it's an angular app) ?